# Logoff all users remotely except specific users

Tags: batch-file

The below script checks for the mentioned users among the listed remote servers and if the mentioned user names are found then it will log off the users from the listed servers remotely. This works fine as expected.

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL
SET "users=USER01 USER02"
SET "servers=SERVER1 SERVER2 SERVER3 SERVER4"
FOR %%s IN (%servers%) DO (
    FOR /f "tokens=1,2" %%a IN ('"Quser /server:%%s"') DO (
        FOR %%n IN (%users%) DO (
            IF /I %%a==%%n rwinsta /server:%%s %%b          
        )
    )
)
```

I further managed to experiment and now with the below script I am now able to make sure out of 3 users one particular user(USER2) can be skipped from logging off. Rest of the users mentioned under user list will be logged off.

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL
SET "users=USER1 USER2 USER3"
SET "servers=SERVER1 SERVER2 SERVER3 SERVER4"
FOR %%s IN (%servers%) DO (
    FOR /f "tokens=1,2" %%a IN ('"Quser /server:%%s"') DO (
        FOR %%n IN (%users%) DO (
            IF /I %%a EQU %%n IF /I "%%n" NEQ "USER2" rwinsta /server:%%s %%b   
        )
    )
)
```

What I am looking for is, how can I make multiple users to skip the log off? If I added another If condition with NEQ "USER3" it won't work as per the logic.

or

Is there any other way were we can logoff all users except User1, user2 and user3 from mentioned servers?

Any leads would be extremely helpful.

Comment: You know how to define and iterate over lists, just create another one and check that list before removing a user. Another option is to just remove the users you don't want logged off, from the user list.

Comment: TIP: Run `help call`, put the exclusion check in a subroutine that sets an environment variable true if the user is found in the exclusion list. Then check that variable on your inner most if, where you are checking against `"USER2"`.